# Android Studio 1.0 AndroidManifest.xml Overview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, android-drawable

I updated to the 1.0.1 version of android stodio.

But there are many new error.

I encountered the problem is raised by Manifest.

Error log:

```
Error:(19, 5) Attribute application@icon value=(@drawable/ic_con) from AndroidManifest.xml:19:5
Error:(21, 5) Attribute application@theme value=(@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar) from AndroidManifest.xml:21:5
```

Code:

```
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
\\19
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_con"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
\\21
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    >
```

I do not know how to fix

Comment: try changing the ic_con to ic_launcher and the android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar to android:style/Theme.AppCompat

Comment: Very effective is wroking now but why?

Comment: well i guess because if you look at your drawable folder you dont have any icon named ic_con and for some reason it didnt like your theme with no title bar..however you can change theme anytime because appcompat is the default i think....anyway i am glad it worked